# problems in DAEMON Tools Lite

Tags: windows-7

i installed DAEMON Tools Lite and removed it off from my computer then when i wanted to re-install it there is a box appeared written on it internal setup error.code 14.contact support

Comment: Which version are you using? 32-bit or 64-bit? The link in Neal's answer points to users having 64-bit Windows Vista and 7.

Answer (score 0):

It may [relate to your security software](http://forum.daemon-tools.cc/f14/internal-setup-error-error-code-14-contact-support-cant-install-lite-pro-24834/). Try disabling it and having another go.